# DEX failure when including multiple libs using Realm

Tags: java, android, realm

I need to include two libraries in my project, both of those define their own RealmObjects. I keep getting the following error:
com.android.dex.DexException: Multiple dex files define Lio/realm/RealmJsonImpl;

When I remove all RealmObjects from one of those libs, everything works fine.

Is this something about preprocessing of realm? It is necessary that I can use both libraries with their own RealmObjects. Is there a possibility?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Realm didn't support library projects before 0.81.1. However with 0.81.1 RealmModules were released which allow you to use Realm in library projects. You can read more here: https://realm.io/news/realm-java-0.81.1/

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I was stumbling in this particular problem. Gonna try RealmConfiguration.